# Getting "IndexError: tuple index out of range" when I use Variable instead of List

Tags: python, formatting

**Trying to get the output of final data in a table format. I don't think there is any parsing error as when I use the "print(finalData)" output instead of variable "finalData" in "for args in (finalData):" it is working.**

```
stnID =['1', '25', '2', '24', '3', '4', '5', '6', '8', '28']
stnName =['KSP', 'SBAEC', 'KAMA', 'NAFNS', 'PNU', 'RP', 'AD', 'KH', 'WHAD', 'NGH']
ppt =['10.0', '8.5', '70.1', '21', '13', '41', '56', '76', '8.23', '82']

finalData =("('StnID', 'Station Name', 'PPT mm'), ('===', '=======', '==='), ")

for x in range(len(stnName)):
    finalData = finalData + "('" + stnID[x] + "', '" + stnName[x] + "', '" + ppt[x] + "'), "

finalData= finalData + "('===', '=============', '============')"
print(finalData)

for args in (finalData):
    print '{0:>4} {1:<40} {2:>12}'.format(*args)
```

Comment: `finalData` is a string, so what do you expect `args` to be in your last loop, if not a single character?

Comment: Didn't know. Thank for enlightening. Will review again.